# JQuery changing content of table cell

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell, innerhtml

OK, this is an *embarrassingly* simple question. Why doesn't the following jQuery example work? Obviously it is supposed to change the 'a' in the table to 'hello'.

HTML code:

```
    <table id='table1'>
      <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
      </tr>
    </table>​
```

JavaScript (JQuery) code:

```
    $("#table1 td:contains('a')").innerHTML="hello";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the html function like this

```
 $("#table1 td:contains('a')").html("hallo");
```

if you want use innerHTML (is a DOM method, not a Jquery Method), you have to select the DOMElement first.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#table1 td:contains('a')").each(function(){
    jQuery(this)[0].innerHTML = "Hallo";
    });
});
```

Comment: @user1069609 look the second part in my answer

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because `innertHTML` is a property of a DOM element and not of the jQuery object. You want

```
$("#table1 td:contains('a')").html("hello");
```