# My JQuery fails to select table cells containing nonbreaking space `&nbsp;` or `&#160;`

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, html-table, html-entities

Inspired from the post [JQuery changing content of table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411459/jquery-changing-content-of-table-cell) , I am trying to modify the content of table cells containing a particular string which includes non breaking white spaces `&nbsp;` or equivalently `&#160;`, but I can't seem to make it work in my case.

Html code:

```
    <table id='table1'>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;a</td>
         <td>b</td>
      </tr>
    </table>​
```

JQuery:

```
  $("#table1 td:contains('&nbsp;a')").html("hallo");
```

It has no effect.

Another question: Is there a selector stricter than `contains`, selecting only the cells with exactly a given string?

Comment: This seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282250/jquery-contains-returns-nothing-for-html-encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), you can select elements based on any custom criteria you want.

```
$('#table1 td').filter(function()
{
    return $(this).html().indexOf('&nbsp;a') !== -1;

}).html('hallo');
```

or to answer your other question:

```
$('#table1 td').filter(function()
{
    return $(this).html() === '&nbsp;a';

}).html('hallo');
```

This is a lot more robust than writing convoluted selector strings.

Comment: Thanks it works great. I am still frustrated that my example doesn't work, conceptually it should, right?

Comment: I think `:contains()` searches the text, not HTML (so `&nbsp;` would not appear).

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Could you explain what is meant by "convoluted selector strings", or point to some good resource ?